# How can I use LiveData or Flow for moving to the next Activity or Fragment after Successful response?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I often face the situations that I need to move to the next screen(or even the previous screen or showing/hiding dialogs, etc.) after getting the response from Server.

Here's an example that shows popup when it's an unread popup.

```
    fun fetchPopup() = viewModelScope.launch {
        remoteConfig.fetchPopup()
            .collectLatest { popup ->
                if(preferenceRepository.isUnreadPopup(popup.key)) _popup.postValue(popup)
                else _popup.postValue(null)
            }
    }
```

```
    fun fetchPopup() = viewModelScope.launch {
        remoteConfig.fetchPopup()
            .filter { popup ->
                preferenceRepository.isUnreadPopup(popup.key)
            }.collectLatest {
                _popup.postValue(it)
            }
    }
```

```
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            remoteConfig.fetchPopup().collect { popup ->
                if (preferenceRepository.isUnreadPopup(popup.key)) {
                    _popupUiState.value = PopupUiState.Success(popup)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried these codes But

And this is in the HomeFragment for observing the data.

```
        lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel.popupUiState.collect { uiState ->
                    when (uiState) {
                        is HomeViewModel.PopupUiState.Success -> {
                            if(uiState.popup != null) initEventPopup(uiState.popup)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

And here's a popup that uses in the Navigation Jetpack library.

```
    private fun initEventPopup(popup: Popup) {
        val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionNavigationHomeToEventPopup(popup)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

And I get this error too.

```
Process: io.example.dev, PID: 25579
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination io.example.dev:id/action_navigation_home_to_event_popup cannot be found from the current destination Destination(io.example.dev:id/event_popup) label=EventPopup
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1540)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1472)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1930)
        at io.example.ui.home.HomeFragment.initEventPopup(HomeFragment.kt:83)
        at io.example.ui.home.HomeFragment.initFragment$lambda-9(HomeFragment.kt:77)
        at io.example.ui.home.HomeFragment.$r8$lambda$c2lOPJzdECpYISIKPhhO714Ch5U(Unknown Source:0)
        at io.example.ui.home.HomeFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:93)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: I saw you're trying to navigate from activity to another fragment by using `HomeFragment`. Your action is from `HomeFragment` to `EventPopup`, not from activity. So, in `initEventPopup` function, you need to create a new global action to redirect from activity to another fragment.

Comment: No, I am not trying to navigate from activity to another fragment. I am just trying to open a DialogFragment from a Fragment, which is HomeFragment. @DươngMinh

Comment: I'm not sure if you can navigate from `HomeFragment` to `EventPopup` when calling the action inside your `Activity`. Try creating a global action to `EventPopup` so you can call it while you are in the activity.

Comment: @mohammadfakhraee I am not navigating HomeFragment to EventPopup inside my Activity, but HomeFragment.